# jest timeout error: Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test

Tags: typescript, express, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have created a unit test case for controller and mocking the request, response and next while running the test case it's throw jest timeout error.

Anyone help me resolve that issue.

**employee.controller.ts**

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { employeeService } from './employee._service';

const empServices = new employeeService();

module employeeController {
    export async function getEmployee(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        try {
            const result = await empServices.getEmployee();
            res.send(result);
            return result;
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.send("error in getEmployee: " + err);
        };
    };
}
export { employeeController }
```

**employee.controller.spec.ts**

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { employeeController } from '../employee.controller';
import { employeeService } from '../employee._service';

describe("should return pong message", () => {
    const service = new employeeService();
    it("should return pong message", async () => {

        const mockRequest: any = {
            body: jest.fn(),
            params: jest.fn()
        };

        const mockResponse: any = {
            json: jest.fn(),
            status: jest.fn(),
        };

        const mockNext: NextFunction = jest.fn();

        const spy = jest.spyOn(service, 'getEmployee').mockResolvedValueOnce([]);
        const comments = await employeeController.getEmployee(mockRequest, mockResponse, mockNext);
        expect(comments).toEqual([]);
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith()
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    });
});
```

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO5xr.png)

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean to mock your `employeeService` too? How does that service execute the `getEmployee` method?

Answer (score 0):

One way, which worked for me, would be to increase the timeout value to a number suiting your needs;  in this example 60 seconds:

```
beforeEach((): void => {
    jest.setTimeout(60000);
    ...
  });
```

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11607

Answer (score 0):

for CRA users we can put `jest.setTimeout(ms)` in the `setupTests` file to increase timeout globally in case that other tests are failing in the same reason.